# Can I map random strings to two classes faster than a naive hash table?

Tags: c++, algorithm, hashmap

I have a large number of random strings of fixed length (10m+ strings to process, 32 characters, around 200k unique strings) that I want to map to two categories. I know which random strings map to which category, I want to be able to stream in these strings and get their category as quickly as possible.

At the moment I am using a hash table (C++ unordered_map) from strings to 0/1. Is any pre-processing I could do or anything about the fact there are only two categories I'm mapping to which would allow me to do this more efficiently?

Comment: did you try a vector?

Comment: Switch over the first different letter in the strings.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways do make this (possibly) more efficient:

- You might be able to find faster/better hashing algorithms and/or a generally faster hash map implementation for your usage case
- Precomputing the hash of each string and storing that in an wrapper struct might improve performance, as the hash is only computed once per string
- Depending on how you determinate which string coresponds to which category, a finite state machine could replace the hash map (this could be anything from a couple of simple branches to something as complex as regex).
- There are propably even more ways to improve the performance that I don't think of right now

Which of those optimizations (if any) actually improve the performance would need to be tested. These are just the things I would try first.